# Requesting code as answers

Tags: feature-request

It's disappointing that Stack Overflow asks questioners to submit a minimum reproducible example when asking questions, but some people  answer using just a copy and pasted documentation link to read as an answer.

Stack Overflow needs to make answerers accountable for their answers and should convince them to produce minimum level of coding in their answers and not documentation links as an answers.

Comment: If someone posts an answer that’s basically just a link, you can flag it as Not An Answer. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Good explanations are sometimes more useful than plenty lines of code.

Comment: @Damien yes I agree, good explanation is useful than plenty of code but it's stackoverflow- people come here with an expectation to get an answers for their problems . posting Some documentation links as answers are not good explanation for their particular issue.

Comment: @user3597223 As stated above, a link-only answer is not a good explanation. Generally speaking, if an answer is considered as bad, it is very likely that it will be downvoted. No need to add too specific rules.

Comment: I feel like this would be more useful with some examples. *Many* answers do *not* need complete, working code, because the question does not request such code – rather it seeks explanations. That the question has to provide a complete example is because it is the only one that can set this context, whereas an answer can rely on this context existing in the question.

Comment: @Damien I am suggesting this specific rules because what makes stackoverflow unique than other site is people expect some code with a good explanation for their question.dont you think?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi okay that's another perspective.i understand.how about explaining with their questionnaire code and point out where the mistakes been made than vague links as an answer

Comment: @user3597223 It seems your issue is that you have gotten a *bad* answer, and it not having any code is only an incidental issue for the specific case. Feel free to downvote answers that are not useful.

Comment: @gnat No because Imagine you post a question and you got only one answer that's too a link.marking "not as an answer" do nothing good.requesting explanation with some code or point out where the mistakes been made in their code is better solution that I think

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70746208/3122701) is the one that has triggered this particular complaint.

Comment: @F1Krazy yeah why not! Ideas and suggestions always come from the problems that people face. Is it wrong for suggesting this idea.

Comment: @user3597223 I wasn't making any particular judgement about your suggestion or its validity, I was merely providing context for those (like MisterMiyagi above) who were wondering what may have prompted this suggestion.

Comment: @user3597223 - I disagree; As someone that has been programming since they were 12. Sometimes I only need a concept explained to me. So sometimes an explanation from someone who has a better grasp of a concept and a link to the documentation is exactly what I need.  Once I understand a concept I can write virtually any code myself.

Comment: "Stack Overflow needs to make answerers accountable for their answers" - ... they are. If they weren't, you wouldn't be able to get *answer* banned.

Comment: *"marking "not as an answer" do nothing good.requesting explanation with some code or point out where the mistakes been made..."* If you would rather just ask the person to update their answer than use the site to require them to fix it then why is this question tagged with "feature request"? What are you actually asking for in your question? You've already asked that user for more information; if that's how you prefer to handle it, what do you want done/changed?

Comment: @BSMP if the question got only one answer and that's too a vague link and not satisfying or didn't solve the problem then we have to beg that person for updating their answer or for more explanation.thats why I suggested as feature requests like minimal code should added by answerer with more explanation or like requesting explation button - if answerer update the answer for questionaire then answerer can get extra badge or points.it will greatly help if the questionaire gets only one answer

Answer (score 14):

The need for a Minimal Reproducible Example has a different impact on questions than answers:

- The question sets the topic of the Q&A; as such, it must provide all the information to accurately reproduce this *without any context*.
- In contrast, an answer always exists in the scope of the question; as such, it can rely on the context of the question.

For answer code to be *minimal*, it is often important to omit parts that are already provided by the question. Needlessly duplicating them only adds noise that detracts from the important parts.
In the extremes, *no* code needs changing. Answers that merely provide explanations or references are fine in such cases.